# Rails many to many API query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, has-many-through

### Situation

I have 3 models as the following

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :people, through: :ownerships
end
```

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :houses, through: :ownerships
end
```

and

```
class Ownership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :house
  belongs_to :person
end
```

### Expected result

Basically, I'd like to make a query as JSON to get a list of all `houses` with associated `people`. The point is some houses don't have any people and some people don't own a house so the `Ownership` association doesn't have all the houses' ids. If a house doesn't belong to any person so the response should be nil.

The result from the query is, for example, the following:

```
{
  house1: {
    owners: [
      person1,
      person2
    ]
  },
  house2: {
    owners: null
  },
  house3: {
    owners: [
      person2
    ]
  }
}
```

### What I've tried

I tried to use `includes` but I got separated arrays of items without the associated structure.

```
House.all.includes(:people).as_json(include: [:people])
```

but `people` value is in a separated key and not associated with the `houses`.

Comment: Have you tried `House.all.as_json(include: {ownerships: :person})` or `House.all.preload(:people).as_json(include: {ownerships: :person})`. Generally I would recommend using a true presenter pattern, I am extremely partial to `grape` and `grape-entity` for API interaction as the DSL is extremely reusable and flexible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for query you can as below

```
House.includes(ownerships: :person).as_json(include: [:people])
```

this will return house with your expected result.
inside your includes, you type the relations between house -> ownerships (plural) then from ownership -> person (singular since ownership belong to)

Comment: Oh, I just tried it and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot. I spent a lot of time trying to figure it out. I still don't quite get the includes syntax and the way it actually works though. All in all, this is pure magic.